# How to call Wso2bps using wso2esb

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.8.0 and wso2bps3.0.1 while i am working with 2 servers both are working fine .But i wish incorporate both severs for that i written sample BPEL
sample BPLE file is like this

```
<bpel:process name="multiply2integers"
         targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample"
         suppressJoinFailure="yes"
         xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample"
         xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
         >

    <!-- Import the client WSDL -->
    <bpel:import location="multiply2integersArtifacts.wsdl" namespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample" 
            importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />

    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- PARTNERLINKS                                                      -->
    <!-- List of services participating in this BPEL process               -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:partnerLinks>
        <!-- The 'client' role represents the requester of this service. -->
        <bpel:partnerLink name="client"
                     partnerLinkType="tns:multiply2integers"
                     myRole="multiply2integersProvider"
                     />
    </bpel:partnerLinks>

    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- VARIABLES                                                         -->
    <!-- List of messages and XML documents used within this BPEL process  -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:variables>
        <!-- Reference to the message passed as input during initiation -->
        <bpel:variable name="input"
                  messageType="tns:multiply2integersRequestMessage"/>

        <!-- 
          Reference to the message that will be returned to the requester
          -->
        <bpel:variable name="output"
                  messageType="tns:multiply2integersResponseMessage"/>
    </bpel:variables>

    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- ORCHESTRATION LOGIC                                               -->
    <!-- Set of activities coordinating the flow of messages across the    -->
    <!-- services integrated within this business process                  -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:sequence name="main">

        <!-- Receive input from requester. 
             Note: This maps to operation defined in multiply2integers.wsdl 
             -->
        <bpel:receive name="start" partnerLink="client"
                 portType="tns:multiply2integers"
                 operation="process" variable="input"
                 createInstance="yes"/>

        <!-- Generate reply to synchronous request -->
        <bpel:assign validate="no" name="Assign">
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from>
                    <bpel:literal>
                        <tns:multiply2integersResponse xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><tns:mul>0</tns:mul>

                        </tns:multiply2integersResponse>
                    </bpel:literal>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to variable="output" part="payload"></bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from>
                    <![CDATA[$input.payload/tns:c*$input.payload/tns:d]]>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to part="payload" variable="output">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:mul]]></bpel:query>
                </bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
        </bpel:assign>
        <bpel:reply name="end" 
               partnerLink="client"
               portType="tns:multiply2integers"
               operation="process" 
               variable="output"
               />
    </bpel:sequence>
</bpel:process>
```

even i am publishing my bpel wsdl also
if i try with wso2bps TRYIT tool its working fine but while calling with wso2esb is not working
WSDL file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="multiply2integers"
        targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample"
        xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample"
        xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        >

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     TYPE DEFINITION - List of types participating in this BPEL process 
     The BPEL Designer will generate default request and response types
     but you can define or import any XML Schema type and use them as part 
     of the message types.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    
    <types>
        <schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
                targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample" 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

            <element name="multiply2integersRequest">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="c" type="int"/>
                                                <element name="d" type="int"/>

                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>

            <element name="multiply2integersResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="mul" type="int"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>


<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     MESSAGE TYPE DEFINITION - Definition of the message types used as 
     part of the port type defintions
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    
    <message name="multiply2integersRequestMessage">
        <part name="payload" element="tns:multiply2integersRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="multiply2integersResponseMessage">
        <part name="payload" element="tns:multiply2integersResponse"/>
    </message>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     PORT TYPE DEFINITION - A port type groups a set of operations into
     a logical service unit.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    

    <!-- portType implemented by the multiply2integers BPEL process -->
    <portType name="multiply2integers">
        <operation name="process">
            <input  message="tns:multiply2integersRequestMessage" />
            <output message="tns:multiply2integersResponseMessage"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>   
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     PARTNER LINK TYPE DEFINITION
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    
    <plnk:partnerLinkType name="multiply2integers">
        <plnk:role name="multiply2integersProvider" portType="tns:multiply2integers"/>
    </plnk:partnerLinkType>


<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     BINDING DEFINITION - Defines the message format and protocol details
     for a web service.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <binding name="multiply2integersBinding" type="tns:multiply2integers">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="process">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://wso2.org/bps/sample/process" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     SERVICE DEFINITION - A service groups a set of ports into
     a service unit.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <service name="multiply2integers">
        <port name="multiply2integersPort" binding="tns:multiply2integersBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://*********:8080/multiply2integers" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

and i written sample proxy which will call the BPEL endpoint that sample proxy define below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="BPELProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="value1"
                   expression="//c/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="value2"
                   expression="//d/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:AddingPLRequest xmlns:p="http://wso2.org/bps/sample">
                  <c xmlns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample">$1</c>
                  <d xmlns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample">$2</d>
               </p:AddingPLRequest>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('c')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('d')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="BPEL"/>
         </send>
       </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
    </proxy>

defined endpoint view is my endpoint is

 <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="BPEL">
   <address uri="http://*************:9763/services/multiply2integers/" format="soap12">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

i am sending request from CURL command to ESB I am getting errors my CURL Command is.
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"c":"55","d":"3"}' http://*******t:8282/services/BPELProxy
and its showing errors if i change the format of endpoint its showing some other error error log like this

```
[2014-01-13 15:20:01,070]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-01-13 15:20:01,070+0530]
[2014-01-13 15:22:44,887]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2014-01-13 15:22:44,0886] from IP address null while trying to authenticate access to service StatisticsAdmin
[2014-01-13 15:22:44,887] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.statistics.ui.StatisticsAdminClient} -  Cannot get service stats for service multiply2integers. Backend server may be unavailable.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.
```

Comment: <soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Code><soapenv:Value>axis2ns1:Client</soapenv:Value></soapenv:Code><soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://192.168.1.201:9763/services/AddingPL/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Detail></soapenv:Detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body>

Comment: INFO - LogMediator To: /services/BPELProxy, MessageID: urn:uuid:8ac4d0cf-05c8-474f-8324-83c5cca11aba, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><c>55</c><d>3</d></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2014-01-13 15:23:08,399]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout